# SVG font-face is not working on Android

Tags: android, css, svg, font-face, zurb-foundation

Downloaded a font from Google fonts, converted it with fontsquirrel.com's tool, added the following css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'kaushan_scriptregular';
    src: url('kaushanscript-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('kaushanscript-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('kaushanscript-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('kaushanscript-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('kaushanscript-regular-webfont.svg#kaushan_scriptregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

The font works perfect in all browsers and devices except on Android smartphones on their standard browser. If I use for instance Chrome for Android, then the font works perfectly. I must refer that I am using Foundation5 and that I already replaced the font-family in all the CSS!

**Please note** that if the files were not in the right folder or if the CSS @font-face would be wrong, then it wouldn't work on a computer in the first place. **Note as well** that I have already tried this in other projects with other fonts and it worked fine on Android smartphones.

Anyone knows what the problem might be? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version(s) of Android was this tested on? Font format support varies by version.

Comment: It's Android 4.3 (Jelly bean, I think, it doesn't say on the phone settings, only that it is 4.3). According to my phone, the OS is updated...

Comment: According to http://caniuse.com/#feat=ttf Android 2.2 and newer support TTF and TTF is listed before SVG in your list, so why do you think this is a problem with SVG? Does the Kaushan Script work for you if you use it as hosted by Google Fonts? Works for me on Android 4.1.2.

Comment: Funny thing... I wonder if this is a Foundation5 problem. You ask if it works if I just import the font directly from Google fonts and it does, but then it stops working on the computer...

Comment: Furthermore it cannot be a CSS problem because the font-face still works when I shrink the browser window. I will check on other phones when I get home...